# event handling for button click in visual c++

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to retrive the data from a textfield on the click of a button.

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: Is it managed or unmanaged C++? Are you using any framework (WinForms/WPF/WTL/ATL/MFC/wx/plain Win32/...)? How are you creating the window? Is it a dialog resource or a "plain" window? What code did you write up to now?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a new project of type "Visual C++/CLR/Windows Forms Application" to your solution.
2. Add a button and textbox to the designer.
3. Double-click the button on the designer. This should take you to the form code, where an event handler will have been created and registered for you.
4. In the body of that event handler, you may access the text field using its name from the  design (the name is viewed/modified by right-clicking the item in the form designer and selecting "Properties").

Edit:
I typically don't use C++ for Windows Forms applications, but this example seems to work:

```
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             System::String^ txt = this->textBox1->Text;
             txt += " augmented";
             this->textBox1->Text = txt;
           }
```

Comment: can you please tell me a sample code how to do it,framework used is win32 form  the code is
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
     this->AcceptButton
    }
 private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }

Comment: If you got that code it is a managed project (actually, it's C++/CLI), the framework is the .NET framework and the graphic toolkit is WinForms. <_< By the way, to post that additional info you should edit your original question, so that the code is formatted and indented correctly and other people willing to answer can find immediately all the information needed to answer.

Comment: ok...i have another query....i get the textbox data store it into string format,there are some values as numbers,can i change these string numbers into int format

Answer (score -1):

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)      
{           
    label1 -> Text= "Hello Yashan";  
}
```

this is ok

Comment: down vote. You dont explain how to create the event but you have just shown the event method.